# Streaming arbitrary data with Gstreamer over network

Tags: streaming, gstreamer

How can we use Gstreamer to stream arbitrary data?

In this very informative talk (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZphadMGufY8) the lecturer mentions that Gstreamer is media agnostic and a use case where Gstreamer is used for non-media application so this should be possible but I didn’t find anything useful on internet so far.

Particular use case in which I am interested: high-speed usb bayer camera is connected to RPi4. RPi4 reads and forwards camera frames via network. Now, Gstreamer doesn’t support (as far as I know) sending bayer formatted frames via udp/rtp so I need to convert it to something else i.e. to RGB format using the bayer2rgb element. This conversion, however, consumes some part of the processing power from RPi4 so the speed in which RPi4 can read and send frames from the camera is significantly lower.

On top of that I am using RPi4 as a data acquisition system for other sensors also so it would be great if I could use Gstreamer to stream them all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sender pipeline is

```
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! video/x-bayer,format=bggr,width=1440,height=1080,framerate=10/1 ! rtpgstpay mtu=1500 ! queue ! multiudpsink clients=127.0.0.1:5000
```

The receiver pipeline is

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v udpsrc port=5000 caps="application/x-rtp, media=(string)application, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)X-GST" ! queue ! rtpgstdepay ! bayer2rgb ! videoconvert ! autovideosink
```

Take care of the mtu, as far as I know, PI supports 1500 bytes only, no Jumbo Frames.
Also expected missing packages.